# Go from Array of FirebaseListObservables to Array of Strings

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

EDITED TO INCLUDE MORE DETAIL:

Let's assume I have a collection of Survey objects in Firebase, and a collection of SurveyTaker objects in Firebase, and a surveyTakersBySurvey relationship setup like

```
+-- surveyTakersBySurvey
   |
   +-- survey1
   |    |
   |    +-- surveyTaker1 = true
   |
   +-- survey2
        |
        +-- surveyTaker1 = true
```

This code currently works

```
findSurveyByState(surveyState:string): Observable<Survey> {
    return this.db.list('surveys', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'state',
            limitToFirst: 1,
            equalTo: surveyState
        }
    })
    .map(results => results[0]);
}

findSurveyTakerKeysPerSurveyState(surveyState:string,
                           query: FirebaseListFactoryOpts = {}): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.findSurveyByState(surveyState)
        .do(val => console.log("survey",val))
        .filter(survey => !!survey)
        .switchMap(survey => this.db.list(`surveyTakersBySurvey/${survey.$key}`,query))
        .map( stsbs => stsbs.map(stbs => stbs.$key) );
}
```

I need to change the above code to work for multiple surveys returned with the same state.

I'm struggling with rxjs programming...

```
//i first changed this to return multiple
findSurveysByState(surveyState:string): Observable<Survey[]> {
    return this.db.list('surveys', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'state',
            equalTo: surveyState
        }
    })
    //.map(results => results[0]);
}

// this is the method that is not working
findSurveyTakerKeysPerSurveyState(surveyState:string,
                           query: FirebaseListFactoryOpts = {}): Observable<string[]> {
    //need to update to take multiple Surveys
    return this.findSurveysByState(surveyState)
        .do(val => console.log("surveys",val))
        .filter(survey => !!survey)
        //.switchMap(survey => this.db.list(`surveyTakersBySurvey/${survey.$key}`,query))
        // switchMap would only make sense for one at a time?
        .map(surveys => surveys.map(survey => this.db.list(`surveyTakersBySurvey/${survey.$key}`, query)))
        // on the below line i get [ts] Property '$key' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'.
        .map( stsbs => stsbs.map(stbs => stbs.$key) );
}
```

I get an [undefined, undefined]

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if i need to elaborate on anything important.. i'm still feeling my way around here.

EDIT: this.db is from ... import { AngularFireDatabase } from "angularfire2/database";

Comment: when you console.log('stbss'), does it already contains the `.$key` in each of the element of the array?

Comment: It prints array of two FirebaseListObservables ... [FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseListObservable] ... i'm not sure how to print them out.

Comment: if you are using chrome console, you should be able to expand and see the objects inside

Comment: Yea it's a big crazy object like .

0
:
FirebaseListObservable
$ref
:
U {u: Qg, path: E, m: lf, Nc: false, then: undefined, …}
operator
:
ObserveOnOperator {scheduler: ZoneScheduler, delay: 0}
source
:
FirebaseListObservable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ, $ref: U}
_isScalar
:
false
__proto__
:
Observable

Comment: it appears to be the same objects as a this.db.list('foo', query) . .. i'm just not sure how to map those to an array of strings

Comment: @SurajRao, i'm still not sure how to solve.  if i console.log('sbtss:', sbtss.snapshotChanges()) .  i get this error [ts] Property 'snapshotChanges' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>[]'.

Comment: or even [ts] Property 'snapshotChanges' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'.

Comment: It seems you are on old version of `firebase`, so no worry about `snapChanges` right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `combineLatest`.

```
findSurveyTakerKeysPerSurveyState(surveyState:string,
    query: FirebaseListFactoryOpts = {}): Observable<string[]> {
  //need to update to take multiple Surveys
  return this.findSurveysByState(surveyState)
  .do(val => console.log("surveys",val))
  .filter(survey => !!survey)
  //.switchMap(survey => this.db.list(`surveyTakersBySurvey/${survey.$key}`,query))
  // switchMap would only make sense for one at a time?
  .switchMap(surveys => {
    let observables = [];
    surveys.forEach(survey => {
      observables.push(this.db.list(`surveyTakersBySurvey/${survey.$key}`, query));
    });
    return Observable.combineLatest(observables);
  })
  .map( stsbs => stsbs.map(stbs => stbs.$key) );
}
```

You may need to import these two lines.

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Comment: Well, you are just amazing. Thank you.  I also needed to add .map( stsbs => stsbs.map(results => results[0]).map(stbs => stbs.$key) );

Comment: Glad to hear that.